# ¿Porque el navegador puede aplicar estilos con la propiedad style si lo que se esta actualizando es solo una propiedad de objeto?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Lo que se cambia acá es una propiedad llamada styles, pero como se da cuenta el navegador cada vez que se cambia el valor de esta propiedad?

Con javascript no se si existe alguna manera de que se controle el cambio de una propiedad por medio de algún tipo de evento.

No se si en la practica saber el mecanismo que aplica el navegador para realizar estas operaciones sea útil, ¿es vital saberlo?

```
let div =document.getElementById("id")
div.style.backgroundColor="blue";

<div id="id">

</div>
```

Comment: No es vital saber eso, pero si se pueden detectar los cambios con javascript. Usando MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver.

Comment: ¿La pregunta es por simple curiosidad o tienes alguna duda/problema puntual?